# Replace the prebuilt kernel in the Android Platform Source

Tags: android, kernel, platform

I have successfully built and run a version of the goldfish kernel in the emulator. What I want to do now is include this in the platform source I have. So that I can build and run the platform from scratch with my custom kernel.

I have looked everywhere for help in replacing the kernel that is already there. I believe I need to change the 'TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL=' line in a build file somewhere but I can't find the right place.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to change the configuration files. You can override them at the command line. If you export `TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL="Path to my zImage"` and then build the platform. When you build the platform, it will use your `zImage` as part of `mkbootimg` instead of the default.

However, if you did want to change this its under `$(ANDROID_ROOT)/device/<my device>/device.mk`.

So if you were building for the Galaxy Nexus, you would modify the file `device/samsung/tuna/device.mk`.